A riddle with seemingly-unrelated clues


I am Catholic, but my boss isn't the pope.

I am black, but people say I'm light.

Moving one step, I can play a chord.



What am I?

Is this

 a chess bishop, similar to I'm Not A Racist Warrior!?


 The black bishop on square c8 would seem to fit all requirements:

 A bishop is Catholic, but his boss here is a king, not a pope;
 The bishop on c8 is black, but usually referred to as a "light-squared bishop";
 The one step move to square b7 is notated as Bb7, a B-flat seventh chord in music.

